# Unit testing methods with void type

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, unit-testing

I've got some code as shown below with multiple methods which call a web service to get some data from a database.  This will produce a set of fields which are then added to another database from the web app.  This all works great but I have no idea how to unit test any of it due to it mostly outputting voids, and the data coming from a database which changes every time the button is clicked.  Is there a way to unit test to just if the methods work or not?  Sorry I am very new to unit testing but I know how important it is so any help would be appreciated.

```
    //Get webservice service
    private Service1 GetService()
    {
        return new TestProjectService.Service1();
    }

    //Choose which webservice we want to use based on radio button selection
    private TestProjectService.CommandMessages GetCommand(Service1 service)
    {
        var command = new TestProjectService.CommandMessages();

        switch (WebServiceRadio.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                command = service.GetData();
                break;
            case 1:
                command = service.GetDataLINQ();
                break;
        }

        return command;
    }

    //Display the results in a label on screen
    private void DisplayResult(string text)
    {
        LatestCommandLabel.Text = text;
    }

    //Get the current username of the user logged in
    public string GetUsername()
    {
        return System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    }

    //Submit the data to the database using Linq
    private void SubmitData(string username, TestProjectService.CommandMessages command)
    {
        var dc = new TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext();

        var msg = new TestProjectCommandMessage
        {
            Command_Type = command.CommandType,
            Command = command.Command,
            DateTimeSent = command.DateTimeSent,
            DateTimeCreated = command.DateTimeCreated,
            Created_User = username,
            Created_Dttm = DateTime.Now
        };

        dc.TestProjectCommandMessages.InsertOnSubmit(msg);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }

    //Return the value and submit data to database
    private void ReturnValue()
    {
        var service = GetService();
        var command = GetCommand(service);
        var username = GetUsername();

        if (command != null)
        {
            DisplayResult(String.Format("Last Command Called (Using {0}) : {1}", WebServiceRadio.SelectedItem.ToString(), command.Command));
            string userName = GetUsername();
            SubmitData(username, command);
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayResult("No Commands Available");
        }
    }

    //Onlick return value
    protected void GetCommandButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReturnValue();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem. Why would you think your method has to return anything in order to examine whether the changes has been saved or not?

Comment: I am new to unit testing - I know how to unit test a method that brings out a string for example.  However with a void I am not really sure what I am checking against (if that makes sense?!).  The fact that the data in the CommandMessages object is coming from a database also means that I am not sure what the data will be so I am unsure how to get an expected value.

Comment: What methods do you want to unit test?

Comment: Any/All? I want to learn how to do unit testing properly so as much practice as I can get with any that can be tested above would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Behavior verification](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) is the approach used to test methods that don't return any values.

In a nutshell, since the method doesn't return any results, the only thing a test can do is make sure the method causes the appropriate actions to take place. This is typically accomplished by using a [mock object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html), which keeps track of whether or not its methods have been called.

In order for your tests to use test doubles, you need to [include seams in the design](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2) of your system.

I *strongly* recommend reading [Dependency Injection in .Net](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501), by Mark Seeman. Since you're new to unit testing, you undoubtedly have many questions on the mechanics involved in unit testing (and this answer probably sparked even more questions) - this book goes into great detail answering those questions.